# #1690 - DOUBLE value is out of range in 'pow'... on production, works fine locally

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following SQL query

```
select links.id, links.title, links.url, links.user_id, links.created_at, sum(vote) as votes, (sum(vote)) / POWER(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(now(),links.created_at))/3600, 1.8) as rank from links inner join votes on links.id = votes.link_id where links.language_id = 2 group by links.id order by rank, links.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

which works fine locally but on my production server I get an error:

```
#1690 - DOUBLE value is out of range in 'pow((time_to_sec(timediff(now(),`zavoon-news`.`links`.`created_at`)) / 3600),1.8)'
```

my development and production environment both use the same version of MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20

My understanding is the that this part:

```
time_to_sec(timediff(now(),`zavoon-news`.`links`.`created_at`))
```

is getting out of range but I have no idea why. I looked in Google but I couldn't figure it out.

Here is an sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f42838/1

Help much appreciated : )

Comment: Check the underlying data by figuring out which records cause the error.

Comment: A sample data would be required to produce this issue

Comment: Is it possible that one computer is 32 bit and the other 64?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid here is an sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f42838/1

Comment: @Marichyasana both are 64 bit

Comment: You have some invalid data in your production db ..  check selectively  .. for the  find the  table rows  involved  in error  .. and remove or  update the invalid data

Comment: @scaisEdge I did refresh the migrations and with no data in the "links" table the query runs just fine and returns 0 results as exptected; however when I inserted 1 entry into the "links" table the query started giving me the error again.

Comment: @PetarVasilev this `SELECT POWER(-5.8903,1.8)` part in your query generates error

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Does the first argument of POWER need to be positive?

Comment: this happen only with negative first argument and decimal second

Comment: I narrowed it down to MySQL using a different timezone than my app, once made the timezone the same the problem disappeared.